# Need help to develop the list view like file explorer

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am new to XAML and UWP I am developing app in which there is a list of files. So I need basic idea to  do the following task

1. Display all files with their details like name, type, modified date, etc.
2. Perform the operations like sort, copy, view, etc on the list.

So, in short, I want to build the list view similar to the files explorer list view to display files.

[image: listViewExampleImage]

Comment: I think you can write a style.

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: Ya I tried with listview but I am not able to select the header and perform the operation. As in WPF we have GridViewColumnHeader but in UWP I am not finding any way.

Comment: It's quite simple but will need quite a lot of time as you'll need to write all sorts of visual states for the handling cut and drag&drop functionality. The header is a different aspect of the UI, it's not a part of the listview. Can you share what all behaviors of the fileexplorer do you want to implement?

Comment: Thank you for reply, I completed the header part. Now I am doing following tasks COPY,CUT,PASTE,DELETE,Rename

Comment: @Raghva sounds quite like you're off to a head start. I'll work up on a demo and share it as well. it'll take a day as I am currently out of town. Feel free to revert back. Please do mention in the comment (as i've done) so that I get a notification.

Comment: @AdityaSharma yes bro...

Comment: @Raghva have you solved your issue? Or should I start on at a sample project?

Comment: @AdityaSharma thank you for asking and I don't think it is needed now because almost I completed all tasks.

Comment: @Raghva oh great. Do let me know just in case.